# Plot.java on ManagementCompany.java

Tags: java, arrays, overlap

I am currently working on an assignment where we need to  write 3 classes. Property.java ManagementCompany.java and Plot.java.
Right now I am trying to make sure at least my Plot class is running correctly. I don't see any error on my code however the JUnit test that was provided comes back with an error.
Booth the boolean methods is what comes with an error on the JUnit.
Here is what I wrote:

```java
package assignment4;

public class Plot {

    //The x-value of the upper-left corner of the Plot
    private int x;
    //The y-value of the upper-left corner of the Plot
    private int y;
    //The horizontal extent of the Plot
    private int width;
    //The vertical extent of the Plot
    private int depth;


    public Plot() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        width = 1;
        depth = 1;
    }

    public Plot(Plot p) {

        x = p.x;
        y = p.y;
        width = p.width;
        depth = p.depth;
    }

    public Plot(int x, int y, int width, int depth) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.depth = depth;
    }

    // Two rectangles do not overlap if one of the following conditions is true.
    // One rectangle is above top edge of other rectangle.
    // One rectangle is on left side of left edge of other rectangle.
    public boolean overlaps(Plot plot) {
        if (this.x <= plot.x + (plot.width - plot.x) && this.y <= plot.y + (plot.depth - plot.y)) {


            if (plot.x <= this.x + (this.width - this.x) && plot.y <= this.y + (this.depth - this.y))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    //Second boolean
    public boolean encompasses(Plot plot) {
        if (this.x <= plot.x && this.y <= plot.y) {
            return true;
        }
        if (this.depth <= plot.depth && this.width <= plot.width) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public void setDepth(int depth) {
        this.depth = depth;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getDepth() {
        return depth;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Upper left: (" + x + "," + y + "); " + "Width: " + width + " Depth: " + depth;
    }
}
```

Here is the JUnit test:

```java
public class PlotTest {
    private Plot plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4, plot5, plot6, plot7, plot8, plot9,
    plot10, plot11, plot12, plot13;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        plot1 = new Plot(12, 12, 6, 6);
        plot2 = new Plot(10, 10, 2, 2);
        plot3 = new Plot(11, 11, 3, 2);
        plot4 = new Plot(16, 11, 4, 2);
        plot5 = new Plot(13, 14, 4, 3);
        plot6 = new Plot(16, 15, 3, 1);
        plot7 = new Plot(11, 16, 3, 3);
        plot8 = new Plot(16, 17, 4, 2);
        plot9 = new Plot(11, 14, 2, 1);
        plot10 = new Plot(19, 12, 2, 2);
        plot11 = new Plot(12, 12, 3, 2);
        plot12 = new Plot(15, 17, 3, 1);
        plot13 = new Plot(15, 17, 3, 1);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        plot1 = plot2 = plot3 = plot4 = plot5 = plot6 = plot7 = plot8 = plot9 = plot10 = plot11 = plot12 = plot13 = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testOverlaps1() {
        assertTrue(plot1.overlaps(plot11)); //plot11 is entirely inside plot1
        assertTrue(plot11.overlaps(plot1));
    }
    @Test
    public void testOverlaps2() {
        assertTrue(plot1.overlaps(plot3)); //plot3 overlaps the lower left corner of plot1
        assertTrue(plot3.overlaps(plot1));
        assertTrue(plot1.overlaps(plot4)); //plot4 overlaps the lower right corner of plot1
        assertTrue(plot4.overlaps(plot1));
    }
    @Test
    public void testOverlaps3() {
        assertTrue(plot1.overlaps(plot7)); //plot7 overlaps the upper left corner of plot1
        assertTrue(plot7.overlaps(plot1));
        assertTrue(plot1.overlaps(plot8)); //plot8 overlaps the upper right corner of plot1
        assertTrue(plot8.overlaps(plot1));
    }
    @Test
    public void testOverlaps4() {
            assertTrue(plot1.overlaps(plot9)); //plot9 overlaps the left side of plot1
            assertTrue(plot9.overlaps(plot1));
            assertTrue(plot1.overlaps(plot6)); //plot6 overlaps the right side of plot1
            assertTrue(plot6.overlaps(plot1));
        } **
        FAILS HERE **
        @Test
    public void testOverlaps5() {
            assertFalse(plot3.overlaps(plot9)); //plot9 does not overlap plot3
            assertFalse(plot9.overlaps(plot3));
            assertFalse(plot5.overlaps(plot8)); //plot5 does not overlap plot8, but partly share a side
            assertFalse(plot8.overlaps(plot5));
        } **
        IT FAILS HERE **
        @Test
    public void testOverlaps6() {
            assertFalse(plot3.overlaps(plot4)); //plot4 does not overlap plot3
            assertFalse(plot4.overlaps(plot3));
            assertFalse(plot1.overlaps(plot10)); //plot1 does not overlap plot10
            assertFalse(plot10.overlaps(plot1));
            assertFalse(plot2.overlaps(plot1)); //plot2 does not overlap plot1
            assertTrue(plot12.overlaps(plot13)); //plot12 is exactly the same dimensions as plot13
        } **
        ALSO THIS ONE FAILS **
        @Test
    public void testEncompasses1() {
        assertTrue(plot1.encompasses(plot5)); //plot5 is contained in plot1
        assertFalse(plot5.encompasses(plot1));
        assertTrue(plot1.encompasses(plot11)); //plot11 is contained in plot1
        assertFalse(plot11.encompasses(plot1));
        assertTrue(plot1.encompasses(plot12)); //plot12 is contained in plot1
        assertFalse(plot12.encompasses(plot1));

        assertFalse(plot2.encompasses(plot1));
        assertFalse(plot3.encompasses(plot1)); //plot3 overlaps plat1
        assertFalse(plot1.encompasses(plot3));
        assertFalse(plot7.encompasses(plot8)); //plot7 overlaps plat8
        assertFalse(plot8.encompasses(plot7));
    }

    @Test
    public void testToString() {
        assertEquals("Upper left: (12,12); Width: 6 Depth: 6", "" + plot1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetWidth() {
        assertEquals(2, plot2.getWidth());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetX() {
        plot3.setX(22);
        assertEquals(22, plot3.getX());
    }
}
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Hello and Welcome. There is something wrong with if conditions in "overlaps" function. "plot.x + (plot.width - plot.x)"  equates to plot.width, similarly "plot.y + (plot.depth - plot.y)" equates to plot.depth. Then basically you check this.x against target plot.width , this.y against target plot.depth. Fix your if conditions

Comment: for the encompasses function, lines failed are : plot 5 encompass plot1, plot 11 encompass plot1, plot 12 encompass plot1 ,plot 2 encompass plot1 , plot 3 encompass plot1,plot 7 encompass plot8.  This shows that rectangle inside fails encompass function against the outer rectangle surrounding it. you might want to review your encompassing logic.

Comment: I was finally able to figure it out. The tests 5 and 6 were my biggest problem. 
I created and if statement inside another one. And that seemed to work:
public boolean overlaps (Plot plot) {
  boolean result = false;
  if (plot.getX() <= this.x + this.width && 
    this.x <= plot.getX() + plot.getWidth()) {
   result = true;
  }
  if ( this.y < plot.getY() + plot.getDepth() && 
    this.y + this.depth > plot.getY()) {
   if (plot.getX() <= this.x + this.width) {
    if(this.x <= plot.getX() + plot.getWidth()) {
   result = true;
   }
  }
  }
  else {
   result = false;

Comment: Add that piece of code at the end of your question, indicating you've solved your problem. Also what about "encompasses" function. Were able to fix that as well ?